# Can this be done without substitution of values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-theorem

> If $${ \left( 1-{ x }^{ 3 } \right)  }^{ n }=\sum _{ r=0 }^{ n }{ { a }_{ r }{ x }^{ r }{ \left( 1-x \right)  }^{ 3n-2r } } $$ then find $a_r$.

**My first attempt:**

I wrote the above equation as:

$$\sum _{ i=0 }^{ n }{ { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n }{ x }^{ 3n }\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ i \end{matrix} \right)  } =\sum _{ r=0 }^{ n }{ \sum _{ i=0 }^{ 3n-2r }{ { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ i }{ a }_{ r }{ x }^{ r+i }\left( \begin{matrix} 3n-2r \\ i \end{matrix} \right)  }  } $$

From here, I couldn't proceed.

**My second attempt:**

I substituted $x=-1$ and did some algebraic bashing and got ${ a }_{ r }=\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ r \end{matrix} \right) { 3 }^{ r }$.

The answer I got was correct but I feel my method wasn't the expected one. Is there a method to find $a_r$ without any particular substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note
$$(1-x^3)^n=(3x(1-x)+(1-x)^3)^n=\sum _{ r=0 }^{ n }{ 3^r\binom{n  }{ r }{ [x(1-x) ]}^{ r }{ \left( 1-x \right)  }^{ 3n-3r } }=\sum _{ r=0 }^{ n }{ 3^r\binom{n  }{ r }{ x }^{ r }{ \left( 1-x \right)  }^{ 3n-2r } } $$

Comment: I didn't think of this factorisation. Very innovative. Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaKumar This ain't a factorization, I think it's just another way of expressing things.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for that. Now I shall use this method in other problems too.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Forgot that, It's been some time since I asked an question.

Comment: Very imaginative solution! (+1)